# How can i read this object property ? Moltin API

Tags: javascript, moltin

I'm using Moltin API, what i need is take the category id from the current product.

what could be simple like this:

```
product.category.id
```

but,
what i get is....

```
product.category.data.1353881339752874661.id
```

how can i take this object property dynamically?

below is a print from my browser console:

[image: Properties from my product object]

Comment: after product.category.data you have to run a for(var prop in product.category.data){console.log(product.category.data[prop].id)}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo can do that by iterating the Keys of `product.category.data` object.

```
for (var key in product.category.data){
 // use key to refer to each key of the Object.
}
```

Another option could be, getting the different ids using the `Objet.keys()` method.

Comment: I would suggest that you add lodash to you project.. it will help you a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `for/in` loop.

Like this..

```
for(x in product.category.data){
console.log(x.id);
     }
```

See here [for/in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Comment: that's work for me too, but i had to find another solution, because i'm using react, and i get a warning. so what i've found is: Object.keys(product.category.data)[0]